# Token doesn't want to deploy to a blockchain

Tags: ethereum, rpc, ganache, brownie

I have created and compiled a smart contract and created my deploy token file as well. When I run ganache-cli on one terminal it gives me '''eth_getTransactionByHash''' and while the brownie run scripts is running on the other terminal it says '''awaiting transaction from mempool'''

I logged into my MetaMask account as well and created a new Account with the RPC and chain ID provided.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running `ganache-cli`. I fixed it by passing some parameters

```
ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie
```